# How to avoid overly extensive introduction of otherwise unnecessary preliminaries for a minor result?

Tags: citations

For my PhD thesis I have proven a minor result but with the help of a theory that is far apart from my actual subjects.

To have my work self-contained up to a certain level and to make my proof understandable, I should introduce like one page of notions, which I will never use again.

The result is quite different from others. But even if it was just a modification of a known result, I don't think the line

> "... can be obtained by a modification of the proof of XYZ to our
>   needs..."

is appropriate in a PhD thesis.

How should I proceed in such cases?

Comment: I think adding one page of notations and definitions in a PhD dissertation is appropriate (even for adding a useful remark).

Comment: Proof and required not(at)ions could go in an appendix.

Comment: One page in a thesis certainly doesn't seem "overly extensive".

Comment: True, one page is not too much in work of 150 pages. I was more about a particular relation of content to preliminaries that I thought misbalanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An appendix, if allowed by your university style/guidelines (and it usually is), is the best option. It strikes a balance between two legitimate concerns:

- you want your thesis to be self-contained, and you want to showcase the work you've done (as well as convince others of your work's quality)
- in the main text, it may make your message less clear and burden the reader's mind with new notations